Debug "Error: Process completed with exit code 127" in Github Action
We have a rather big C++ project that we are moving from QT5.15.2 to QT6.5.3 and in that process some of our tests have started to fail.
We are building on multiple platforms (Linux, MacOS and Windows) and are therefore using different hosted runners.
On Linux and Mac the build and tests works as before but on Windows some of the tests have started to fail. The only error we get from GitHub is "Error: Process completed with exit code 127". From what I have found that could indicate a missing file. I have tried almost everything at this point to determine what file that might be, but so far with no luck.
This is the step we use for testing
jobs:
  build-and-test:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: ["windows", "linux", "macos"]
        include:
          - os: windows
            runner: 07.04.05-windows-2022-16core
          - os: linux
            runner: 07.04.05-ubuntu-20.04-8core
          - os: macos
            runner: macos-12-large
      fail-fast: true
    runs-on: ${{matrix.runner}}
    env:
      build_type: RelWithDebInfo

  - name: Run cmake
    if: steps.prepare-env.outputs.shouldbuild == 1
    env:
      GITLAB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITLAB_PAT }}
    run: >
      cd build &&
      cmake .. ${{steps.prepare-env.outputs.buildflags}} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{env.build_type}} -DBUILD_NUMBER="Build GI-${{github.run_number}}" -DTEST_REPORT=1
      
  - name: Set permissions on test
    if: matrix.os == 'windows' && steps.prepare-env.outputs.shouldbuild == 1
    env:
      ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG: true
      QT_WIN_DEBUG_CONSOLE: attach
    shell: bash
    run: >
      cd build &&
      cmake --build . --config ${{env.build_type}} -j ${{steps.prepare-env.outputs.cores}} --target MyTest &&
      cd Bin &&
      dir &&
      chmod +x "C:\a\projectName\build\Bin\MyTest.exe" 

  - name: Run test manually
    if: matrix.os == 'windows' && steps.prepare-env.outputs.shouldbuild == 1
    env:
      ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG: true
      QT_WIN_DEBUG_CONSOLE: attach
    shell: bash
    run: >
      cd build &&
      "C:\a\projectName\build\Bin\MyTest.exe"

I've tried running the test before it was build and in that situation I get a 127 as well but with an explanatory "C:\a\projectname\build\Bin\MyTest.exe: No such file or directory"

I've tried running the failing tests manually (by taking the files that the dir command shows are available in the bin folder) on a Windows server that I had available, and they executed without problems.
The difference between the tests that are failing and the ones that are working is that the failing ones are using a custom library that we build ourselves, but the build process hasn't changed, only the QT version. I've verified that the new QT modules that we depend on are present in bin folder on the build server.
In an ideeal world I would log onto the build server and run the test manually from the build output to get some information, but we are stuck with this rather useless 127 error.

Any good ideas as to how I can debug this 127 error?

Did you try using ls or similar command to check the existence of the executable? Is that absolute path correct?

I've inserted a dir command to verify that the executable and all the needed dlls are in the bin folder (including MSVC dlls). If I try to execute the test before it is build, I get a 127 error but with an indication of the missing file. So I'm fairly certain that the executable is there and that it is something else. I've thought about permissions, but some of the tests are working just fine so I've ruled that out.

Please share your complete workflow along with the logs of the workflow run. Add dir or any other commands to highlight the existence of the files.

I've added some more of the workflow as well as some of teh log. I'm working for a client and can't include everything unfortunately.

That screenshot doesn't show the error "No such file or directory". Please update that as well.

In both screenshots, the command C:\a\projectName\build\Bin\MyTest.exe is surrounded by extra spaces in quotes. Please double check that. Not sure if that's because of YAML folding > or your actual workflow may already contain those.

That is due to me being a bit sloppy with the editing. I had to obfuscate the name of the actual program. There are no extra spaces in the quotes in the original name

Please try removing shell: bash and use PowerShell to dir and run the test exe.

So the reason for the error was that we are using a Sentry library which was build against QT5. When I bypassed the tests in order to do a release I was able to try out the application on my own machine which then showed me a pop-up with the dll that was missing (QT5).
By doing some digging with the Dependencies tool I was able to find the culprit.
I still don't understand, why GitHub can't give a usefull answer other than 127, but at least now I can move on.
